# Access GPS data on Unity3d with Android devices

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Is there anyway to acces the gps data on android devices with Unity3D?

I know that iPhones have "iPhoneSettings.StartLocationServiceUpdates()". I'm looking for something similar for android.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can access the gps data in unity3d for android devices in the following way:

```
Input.location.Start ();  //start gps
// any method/member you need from Input.location like timestamp or any positional variables.
Input.location.Stop ();   //stop gps (good for battery economy)
```

You can refer here for more info: 
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LocationService.html

Answer (score 0):

As per this [blog post](http://randomactsofdev.wordpress.com/2011/06/01/unity-and-androids-gps/) you have to used the same API: `iPhoneSettings.StartLocationServiceUpdates()`

Comment: Thanks! Don't you think it would be possible to call a java activity from Unity?